# Regarding Surjectivity in Serre's FAC.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I started my first attempt at reading Serre's FAC and have found myself stuck on the sufficiency of the condition he gives in Proposition II (statement and given proof below). I've been able to figure out the necessity and assuming the open cover $\{U_i\}$ exists with $t_i$ as stated, I believe I understand how to conclude sufficiency, but I cannot seem to make the construction work. I fear I am missing something obvious and/or and consumed too much coffee to think straight.

The notation used in the paper:
$\mathscr{F}_U$ the abelian group associated to $U$, $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$, the sections of $\mathscr{F}$ over $U$, $\phi_U^V$ the morphism of abelian groups $\mathscr{F}_V \to \mathscr{F}_U$ for $U\subset V$, and $\iota:\mathscr{F}_U \to \Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$ the morphism mapping $t$ to the section $x\mapsto \phi_x^U(t)$.

Proposition II: Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$ and $\iota: \mathscr{F}_U \to \Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$ be injective for all open $V\subset U$. Then $\iota: \mathscr{F}_U \to \Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$ is surjective if and only if the following condition is met:

For all open coverings $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ and all systems $\{t_i\}$, $t_i \in \mathscr{F}_{U_i}$ such that $\phi_{U_i \cap U_j}^{U_i} (t_i) = \phi_{U_i \cap U_j}^{U_j} (t_j)$ for all pairs $(i,j)$, there is some $t\in \mathscr{F}_U$ such that $\phi_{U_i}^U(t)=t_i$ for all $i$.

For a proof of sufficiency, the following is given:

The condition is sufficient: If $s$ is a section of $\mathscr{F}$ over $U$, there exists an open covering $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ and elements $t_i \in \mathscr{F}_{U_i}$ such that $\iota(t_i)$ coincides with the restriction of $s$ to $U_i$. It follows that the elements
$\phi_{U_i \cap U_j}^{U_i}(t_i)$ and $\phi_{U_i \cap U_j}^{U_j}(t_j)$
define the same section over $U_i \cap U_j$ so by the assumption $\iota$ they are
equal. If $t \in F_U$ satisfies $\phi_{U_i}^U(t)=t_i$, $\iota(t)$ coincides with $s$ over each $U_i$, thus over $U$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The heart of your question seems to be that you cannot "make the construction work," but it's not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: Assuming my understanding is correct, Serre claims that for a given section $s$, one can construct and open covering $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ with elements $t_i \in U_i$ such that $\iota(t_i) = s|_{U_i}$ for each $i$. This construction seems to be assuming surjectivity of $\iota|_{U_i}$ and thus of $\iota$. 

So I guess I can "simplify" the question to "Is there an obvious specific covering $\{U_i\}$ that obviously has this property, or is there a way to cleverly select elements $t_i$ from a general open covering $\{U_i\}$ that have the property?"

Comment: I don't have the paper in front of me (and I don't recall how Serre defines everything), but what exactly is $\mathscr F_U$ as opposed to $\Gamma(U,\mathscr F)$? Is it the disjoint union of all stalks over $U$? Because from my perspective (i.e. Hartshorne's approach to sheaves) this seems tautological: since $U_i \subset U$, there is always a restriction map on sections $\mathscr F(U) \to \mathscr F(U_i)$, and $t_i$ is just the image of $s$ under this map.

Comment: Serre introduces $\mathscr{F}_U$ as follows: (some omission due to character count)

Give all open $U\subset X$ and abelian group and for all pairs $U \subset V$ a homomorphism $\phi_U^V$ satisfying transitivity. $(\mathscr{F}_U,\phi_U^V)$ defines a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ by 

a) $\mathscr{F}_x = \lim \mathscr{F}_U$ (direct limit) which gives morphism $\phi_x^U:\mathscr{F}_U\to \mathscr{F}_x$

b) For $t\in \mathscr{F}_U$ define $[t,U]:=\{\phi_x^U(t) : x \in U\} \subset \mathscr{F}$. Give $\mathscr{F}$ the topology generated by $[t,U]$.

Comment: The difference with Hartshorne seems to be reconciled via Proposition III, which (assume I am understanding correctly) seems to justify saying something along the lines of "You may assume, up to canonical isomorphims, that every sheaf is of the form $(\mathscr{F}_U, \phi_U^V)$, thus Serre seems to address the possibility that $\mathscr{F}_U$ is distinct from $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$.

Comment: I might have figured out my own question:

Let $s\in \Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$. Cover $s(U)$ by basic open neighborhoods $V_i:=[t_i,W_i]$. Since $U,W_i$ open in $X$, their intersection is open and thus wolog we may assume each $W_i \subset U$. Define $U_i:=s^{-1}(V_i)$. $\{U_i\}$ open covers $U$. Further, see each $V_i=s(U_i)$, but also $V_i$ is the image of the section $\iota(t_i)$ in $\mathscr{F}$. Thus $\iota(t_i)$ corresponds to the restriction of $s$ to $U_i$, and the rest of the proof follows as Serre claims.